# How to display only 1 pixel from loaded image and tile it

Tags: html, css, image, css-sprites

I am building a dashboard that allows me to manage 50+ separate projects. Each project has 3 - 5 Ci builds and I want to display the status of all these builds. I can load a build status badge for each job but I don't have anywhere near enough room to display 5 large badges.

What I want to do is take 1 pixel from this badge that will be either red, green or blue and then tile that one pixel to be a 10*10 pixel square so it's easy to see that all builds are green.

I think that I probably want to do this with css sprites but I've experimented a bit and can't get anywhere close to getting it to work.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use CSS `background-size` property?

You could use the badge as a background image and make it so big that only one pixel will be visible on the tile.

```
.my-tile {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-image: url(YOUR BADGE URL) ;
    background-position: left top;
    background-size: 2000px 2000px; /* as big as you need */
}
```

Also see this working example on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/549bxa6r/

Comment: That does work. I also need to set background position to be pixels to get the portion of the badge that I need.
I'll not tick it just yet in case there are any more elegant solutions that do not require setting a massive scaling factor - although I understand completely why you did it.

Comment: You can use `background-position: Xpx Ypx;`, as explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_background-position.asp